# How to play the intro of Legends of Andor with two players?

Tags: legends-of-andor

I just got Legends of Andor and was trying to play the intro with two players. Having only two heroes, it seems the objectives cannot be reached in one day. Is Andor meant to be played with all heroes always, like e.g. In Mice and Mystics? I couldn't find any hints so far in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to play with 2 characters each, you only have 14 hours to spend with 2 players on a given day vs. 28 with 4 players, so you have way more time with 4.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to reach all the objectives with just two players, and that is the way that it is designed.  Unlike Mice and Mystics, Legends of Andor has much more of a puzzle feel to it and you need to plan carefully in order to accomplish things within the time limits.  Keep in mind that you can move through the castle, that is one thing that often makes people think it takes longer than it really does.

Comment: Yes, the game seems much more strategic to me than M&M. However, I cannot figure out how to achieve the very first goals in one day on the A1, the very first card. Movements alone take more than 7 hours.

Comment: Which characters were you using?  The exact moves will vary based on that.  I can try to figure them out for you if you want, though I don't actually own the game.

Answer (score 2):

*Apologies if I've used any wrong terms. I've only got the German version and translated names and things myself. Feel free to fix them if they don't match the English version of the game.*

The intro legend is definitely possible with any pair of heros. With some combinations it's definitely not trivial, but I quite liked that about it, that it immediately drives home the point that this game has a strong puzzle component, where you need to plan your collaborative actions to achieve the goals with the limited resources you have.

Provided I didn't make any mistakes, below are "walkthroughs" for all 6 possible pairs of heros for the very first legend card on the intro legend. The trickiest one is probably the dwarf and ranger combination. Also for most of these, the solutions are not unique (maybe for all of them).

The number in parentheses represents the number of hours remaining for that particular hero.

**Dwarf & Warrior:**

1. Dwarf → 13 (fog; 3)
2. Warrior → 5 (well; 4)
3. Dwarf → 17 (coins; 2)
4. Warrior passes (3)
5. Dwarf → 18 (merchant; 3)
6. Warrior → 0 (castle; 1)

**Dwarf & Ranger:**

1. Dwarf → 17 (coins; 3)
2. Ranger → 13 (fog; 4)
3. Dwarf → 18 (merchant; 2)
4. Ranger → 5 (well; 1). *Note that this path goes through the castle.*
5. Dwarf passes (1)
6. Ranger → 0 (castle; 0)

**Dwarf & Mage:**

1. Dwarf → 17 (coins; 3)
2. Mage → 11 (fog; 5)
3. Dwarf → 18 (merchant; 2)
4. Mage → 5 (well; 3). *Note that this path goes through the castle.*
5. Dwarf passes (1)
6. Mage → 0 (castle; 2)

**Warrior & Ranger:**

1. Warrior → 5 (well; 4)
2. Ranger → 13 (fog; 4)
3. Warrior passes (3)
4. Ranger → 17 (coins; 3)
5. Warrior passes (2)
6. Ranger → 18 (merchant; 2)
7. Warrior → 0 (castle; 1)

**Warrior & Mage:**

1. Warrior → 17 (coins; 3)
2. Mage → 11 (fog; 5)
3. Warrior → 18 (merchant; 2)
4. Mage → 5 (well; 3). *Note that this path goes through the castle.*
5. Warrior passes (1)
6. Mage → 0 (castle; 2)

**Ranger & Mage:**

1. Ranger → 17 (coins; 4)
2. Mage → 11 (fog; 5)
3. Ranger → 18 (merchant; 3)
4. Mage → 5 (well; 3). *Note that this path goes through the castle.*
5. Ranger passes (2)
6. Mage → 0 (castle; 2)

Of course, this is only the first part of the intro legend, and there's quite a lot more to it. However, I can't really give a detailed walkthrough for this, because the actual outcome depends partly on luck and you'll have to improvise a bit. I suppose, if you have really bad luck it might be impossible to solve it, but we did manage to get through on the first try. It definitely required some thinking though, and the game is supposed to be challenging.

I'm sure there's other ways to solve it, but if you want a hint, here's a neat trick which helped us make it through to the end and which probably applies to most if not all pairs of heros:

> Once we got the final (non-ending) legend card on "day" H, we had one character pick up the scroll and the other move to a field around 36. So on the next turn we could do a sort of torch relay, where the first character brings the scroll to 36, hands it off to the other one who can then use their own moves to get to 71. There we waited for two turns to let the Skral pass and then the goal can easily be reached within one turn.
>  
>  One thing worth noting is that we really needed to use up the monster slots in the top left corner. Every killed monster is "worth" a day, and you'll easily reach day N if you try to kill them all. Note that the monsters that spawn on step H can't really reach the castle at all (the same was true of a few other monsters in our case). Their only point is to create a bottleneck near field 39 on the rush to the goal. Every monster that you allow to reach the castle is one more turn you've got to reach the goal, so it's definitely a trade-off worth considering (and probably necessary to some degree).